# Assume that $x$ and $y$ are differentiable functions of $t$ such that $xy = 8$. How to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ when $x = 4$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 13$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are both differentiable functions of t and find the required values of $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

$$xy = 8$$

(a) Find $\frac{dy}{dt}$, given $x = 4$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 13$.

$$y=\frac{8}{x}\\
y'=-\frac{8}{x^2}\\
dy=-8dx $$

$dt=1$?

Can someone explain if I'm doing this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick and easy:**
1. Taking the differential of the given equation, we get:
$xdy+ydx=0$
2. Since $x=4$, use the original equation to get $y (=2)$
3. Putting it back in our new equation, and dividing by $dt$,  we get: $$4\frac{dy}{dt}+2\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$
4. Put the given value ($\frac{dx}{dt}=13$) to get $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{13}{2}$$

**Note:** even though $y$ and $x$ are given as functions of $t$, it's perfectly valid to proceed by the above method, as long as you're taking *differentials*, and not actually *differentiating y wrt x* .

---

**Aliter:** If you only wish to basic calculus.

$$y=8/x\rightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{8}{x^2}$$
We can write this as:

$$\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=-\frac{8}{x^2}$$

Putting values:

$$\frac{dy/dt}{13}=-\frac{8}{4^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{13}{2}$$

Comment: Did you mean to say alternatively after the horizontal rule?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The word "aliter" _means_ "otherwise". Yes, I meant to say "alternatively". my english is not native so my usage of "aliter" could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid writing $dy=-8dx$, because in basic calculus, the expression $dy$ alone has no meaning - it must be part of a larger expression, like $\frac{dy}{dx}$, for it to make sense (and remember, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is **not a fraction**).

That said, your mistake is differentiating the equation $y=\frac8x$ by $x$, when in fact, you should differentiate it by $t$, so you get

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac8x\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac8x\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{8}{x^2}\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$$

Now, knowing what $x$ is and what $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is, you can calculate $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: In contrast to your first sentence, I'm pretty much used to manipulating $dy$ and $dx$ on their own, especially in differential equations.

Comment: @GaurangTandon so am i. so would dy/dt = 8/x? edit: that's wrong too

Comment: Moreover, as opposed to 5xum, I believe writing $dy/dx=-\frac{8}{x^2}$, i.e. differentiating $y$ wrt $x$ is completely valid, as in this case, we're able to relate $x$ and $y$ as $xy=8$

Comment: @GaurangTandon I didn't say it's not *valid* to differentiate by $x$, it just doesn't lead to the solution - as opposed to differentiating by $t$.

Comment: Actually, it does lead to the solution. See my aliter approach in my solution.